# Need help, clarification on rules for escaping/destroying magic bola

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, immobilized

I'm looking for some help with understanding what options an opponent has when I hit them with my bola.

My ranger has taken the **Bola Training [Multiclass Bola]** feat, so I can forego damage and choose to immobilize the target, and knock prone on crits. I'm throwing a +1 Distance Bola, so the weapon is magical as well.

When I choose to immobilize an opponent, what are the rules for their escape options:

- The bola weapon description says "bolas tangle up opponents", but what are gameplay rules for untangling? Action type, skill check?
- If an opponent chooses to cut the bola, what are the rules for damaging/destroying a magic weapon?
- What would be a DC to break out of a magic bola?
- Do any of the rules for escape change when I'm able to also knock them prone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't ever rely upon the fluff description. That's there just to provide a visual, but the bolas don't entangle, they immobilize, which is a different condition.

The full text for the feat explicitly tells you the durations of the effect: until the end of the target's next turn.
There is no way to end the condition earlier, except if a power or feature explicitly ends that condition.

Being knocked prone changes nothing except you're also prone (you can crawl instead of moving and you need a movement action if you want to stand up).

Comment: I'm embarrassed by the stupidity of somehow overlooking the complete sentence. Thank you.